# The Final Number

Tags: code-golf, number

## Challenge

[image]

Write a program that takes an array of 4 integers (*which represents a sequence of numbers generated by a certain algorithm*)  and returns the next integer that would follow.

We will only be using simple addition, subtraction, multiplication and division algorithms with a constant (i.e non-variable) variation.

For division we will use the `floor` integer values: `133/4 = 33` and `33/4 = 8`

**You can assume that there will always be one single valid return value**

## Test cases

`[14,24,34,44]` should return 54 (addition Algorithm)

`[105,45,-15,-75]` should return -135 (subtraction algorithm)

`[5,25,125,625]` should return 3125 (multiplicative algorithm)

`[256,64,16,4]` should return 1 (division algorithm)

## General rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins the challenge.
- [Standard loopholes are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: This is a simplified version of [What comes next?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3485/194) and borderline duplicate.

Comment: I suggest you avoid the term "variance" here, as it's misleading

Comment: Please exactly specify the formlas.

Comment: You should add a test case with integer division. [261,65,16,4] => 1 for example.

Comment: @LuisMendo I agree - what is the correct way to explain it?

Comment: Maybe "variation"? Or perhaps say "increment/ratio". For division it's not exactly a ratio because of the flooring, but I guess I'd go with that

Comment: In the future, I recommend you to post in [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) before going live so that you can receive other people's comments beforehand.

Comment: You should really add some tests cases for integer division. Almost all replies fail to give correct result for [261,65,16,4], [4,2,1,0], or [2,1,0,0]

Comment: I'd just replace *variation* with *right operand*. That works for all binary operators.

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate vote(s). Finding the algorithm is simpler in the sense that there's only one operation to consider, but at the same time, it's harder because integer division has to be accounted for. I don't think there's porting an answer from the other challenge would be substantially easier than writing one from scratch.

Comment: You should probably specify non-negative integers, as when a division series is negative there are two interpretations. For example `-81/4` is either `21 r 3` or `-20 r -1`.

Comment: ^ (maybe obviously) that should read `-21 r 3`

Comment: @LegionMammal978 `-1` and `0`, presumably. As in `+0`?

Comment: Would be nice if the edge cases were added to the post so people can try them out before posting anything.

Comment: Is `int a,int b,int c,int d` a valid parameter-list instead of `int[]a`, considering the list is always 4 long in the question? Or is `int[]` mandatory when your language supports it?

Comment: I feel like you could do this really easily in Mathematica...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 18 bytes

```
D¥¬QPi`+s-ë`r/s\*î
```

**Explanation**

```
D                   # duplicate
 ¥                  # delta's
  ¬Q                # compare first delta to the other deltas
    P               # product (1 if all deltas are equal, otherwise 0)
     i              # if 1 (we're dealing with addition or subtraction)
      `+s-          # add the difference between the elements to the last element
          ë         # else (we're dealing with multiplication or division)
           `r/      # divide the 2nd element by the 1st
              s\*   # multiply with the 4th element
                 î  # round up
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RMKlwqxRUGlgK3Mtw6tgci9zXCrDrg&input=WzI2MSw2NSwxNiw0XQ)

Comment: The output is wrong with [4,2,1,0] ...

Comment: @Damien: Thanks for letting me know. I fixed it and it even saved me a couple of bytes :)

Comment: Great. Now it validates all my test cases.

Comment: Try edge case for divide by four: `[-325, -82, -21, -6]`

Comment: ...actually I guess the question should either be just for non-negative integers or should specify which convention is to be used.

Comment: It's OK see my comment on the question

Comment: @JonathanAllan: True. Lets wait for clarification from OP. Nice catch on the edge case!

Answer (score 14):

### Javascript (ES6),  <s>44</s>   <s>42</s>  44 bytes (fixed)

```
(a,b,c,d)=>a-b+d-c?d/(a<b?a/b:a/b|0)|0:d+c-b
```

*Saved 2 bytes, following IsmaelMiguel's advice.*
*Fixed version for `[2,1,0,0]` and `[1,0,0,0]` as suggested by edc65*

#### 30 bytes version

For the record, my first attempt was <s>32</s> 30 bytes but was lacking floor() support for the division. It also fails for special cases such as `[2,1,0,0]` and `[1,0,0,0]`.

```
(a,b,c,d)=>c-2*b+a?d*c/b:d+c-b
```

#### Demo

```js
var f =
(a,b,c,d)=>a-b+d-c?d/(a<b?a/b:a/b|0)|0:d+c-b

var test = [
  [ 14, 24, 34, 44 ],     // should return 54 (addition Algorithm)
  [ 105, 45, -15, -75 ],  // should return -135 (subtraction algorithm)
  [ 5, 25, 125, 625 ],    // should return 3125 (multiplicative algorithm)
  [ 256, 64, 16, 4 ],     // should return 1 (division algorithm)
  [ 260, 65, 16, 4 ],     // should return 1 (division algorithm with floor())
  [ 2, 1, 0, 0 ],         // should return 0 (special case of division algorithm)
  [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ]          // should return 0 (special case of division algorithm)
];

test.forEach(l => console.log('[' + l.join`, `+ '] => ' + f(...l)));
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that js has pattern matching.

Comment: @LeakyNun - [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) was indeed introduced in ES6. Note that you can't do `[a,b]=>` for function parameters. The parentheses are required.

Comment: Nice, but you should handle integer division: [260, 65, 16, 4] => 0.9846153846153847. It should give 1

Comment: @Damien - Ah well... I knew someone would notice. ;-) That's fixed.

Comment: What about [2,1,0,0] ? Should give 0. I think it's the only counter example for `b*2==c+a` <=> addition/substraction algorithm

Comment: Why do you use destructive assignment? You could do `(a,b,c,d)=>c-2*b+a?d/(a<b?a/b:a/b|0):d+c-b` and inform that you need to do `f.apply(null, [ 14, 24, 34, 44 ]);` or pass each value individually to the function (`f(14, 24, 34, 44);`). This saves 2 bytes. And is standard practice in Javascript (specially in polyfills and with any of the methods on `Array`).

Comment: @Damien - You're right, and `[1,0,0,0]` is also a problem. Not sure if I can easily fix these special cases.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - Since it is not explicitly forbidden, I suppose I can do that indeed. Thanks!

Comment: [1,0,0,0] is a problem for me too :(

Comment: `(a,b,c,d)=>a-b+d-c?d/(a<b?a/b:a/b|0):d+c-b`, same byte count, works for `2,1,0,0`

Comment: `(a,b,c,d)=>a-b+d-c?d/(a<b?a/b:a/b|0)|0:d+c-b` works even for `1,0,0,0`

Answer (score 11):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>37</s> <s>33</s> 27 bytes

```
b:[E]cL,?:Iz{:+a|:*a|:/a}Lt
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=YjpbRV1jTCw_Okl6ezorYXw6KmF8Oi9hfUx0&input=WzU6MjU6MTI1OjYyNV0&args=Wg) or [verify all test cases](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OjFhOkB3YQpiOltFXWNMLD86SXp7OithfDoqYXw6L2F9THQ&input=W1sxNDoyNDozNDo0NF06WzEwNTo0NTpfMTU6Xzc1XTpbNToyNToxMjU6NjI1XTpbMjU2OjY0OjE2OjRdXQ).

*Saved 10 bytes thanks to @LeakyNun*.

#### Explanation

```
Input = [A:B:C:D]

b:[E]cL,     L = [B:C:D:E]
?:Iz         Create the list [[B:I]:[C:I]:[D:I]:[E:I]]
{            Either…
    :+a          Sum all couples of that list
|            or…
    :*a          Multiply all couples of that list
|            or…
    :/a          Integer divide all couples of that list
}L          The result is L
t           Output is the last element of L
```

As LeakyNun pointed out, we don't need the subtraction case because `I` can be any integer.

Comment: wow, brachylog(& prolog) are awesome

Comment: Addition and subtraction is the same

Comment: [29 bytes](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=YjpbRV1jTCw_OltJXXp7OithfDoqYXw6L2F9THQ&input=WzU6MjU6MTI1OjYyNV0&args=Wg)

Comment: [27 bytes](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=YjpbRV1jTCw_Okl6ezorYXw6KmF8Oi9hfUx0&input=WzU6MjU6MTI1OjYyNV0&args=Wg)

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 65 bytes

```haskell
f l@[a,b,c,d]|[a,b..d]==l=d+b-a|z<-b+0^b=div(d*b)$a-mod(max b a)z
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 40 bytes

```py
lambda(a,b,c,d):[d+c-b,d*c/b][c-2*b+a>0]
```

It's literally the JS answer ported into Python (thanks @LeakyNun!). My previous approach was ridiculously long, but here it is:

### Python 2, <s>169</s> 166 bytes

The second and third levels are a raw tab and a raw tab plus a space, respectively, which plays *really* badly with Markdown, so the tabs have been replaced by 2 spaces.

```py
x=input()
q='%d%s%d'
for i in range(max(x)):
 for o in'+-*/':
  a=1
  for e,n in zip(x,x[1:]):
   try:1/(eval(q%(e,o,i))==n)
   except:a=0
  if a:print eval(q%(x[-1],o,i))
```

Pretty simple; tries every constant and operator it thinks could be the constant, then if the constant/operator combination works for every element in the list (using a `try`/`except` pair to avoid `ZeroDivisionError`s), it prints the result for the last element in the list.

I'm sure there's a better method here, this is the naive method.

Comment: You'd better just port the js answer into Python

Comment: Breaks for `[1,0,0,0]` which should output `0`

Answer (score 3):

## TSQL, 55 bytes

This script is trying adding and subtraction in the same check, then it tries to multiply, if that fails, it must be division.

```
DECLARE 
@1 INT=6561,
@2 INT=729,
@3 INT=81,
@  INT=9

PRINT IIF(@2-@1=@-@3,@*2-@3,IIF(@1*@2=@3,@*@1,sqrt(@)))
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/530802/the-final-number)**

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 63 bytes

```
int f(int[]x)=>2*x[1]-x[0]==x[2]?x[3]+x[1]-x[0]:x[3]*x[1]/x[0];
```

Checks whether the difference between the first and second element is the same as the difference between the second and third element. If so, it does addition/subtraction, otherwise it does multiplication/division.

Answer (score 2):

### R, <s>68</s> 74

Array: 68 bytes

```
function(x)if(x[2]-x[1]==x[3]-x[2])x[4]+x[2]-x[1]else x[4]%/%(x[1]%/%x[2])

> (function(x)if(x[2]-x[1]==x[3]-x[2])x[4]+x[2]-x[1]else x[4]*x[2]/x[1])(c(14,24,34,44))
[1] 54
```

4 inputs: 45 bytes

```
function(a,b,c,d)if(b-a==c-b)d+b-a else d*b/a
```

Bonus solution with `log`, `exp`, `var`, 71 bytes

```
if(var(v<-diff(x<-scan(,1)))==0)x[4]+v[1]else x[4]*exp(diff(log(x)))[1]
```

update: integer division

Comment: Isn't this taking four variables rather than an array? If not you can get rid of the parentheses around `b-a` to save a byte though (and I note that your example calls are adding spaces back in).

Comment: @JonathanAllan You are right. It does not take an array.  The byte count has been updated. The parenthesis are needed due to else, but we can save a byte by adding a space instead. The calls don't need the additional spaces.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said you could save 1 byte rather than 2

Comment: Note, it does not currently handle the integer division requirement fully, e.g. `261,65,16,4` returns `0.9961686` rather than `1` (of course there should be a test case for this in the question).

Comment: @JonathanAllan function(x)if(x[2]-x[1]==x[3]-x[2])x[4]+x[2]-x[1]else x[4]%/%(x[1]%/%x[2])

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 73 bytes

```
(a,b,c,d)=>(x=b-a,c-b==x&&d-c==x)?d+x:(x=b/a,b*x|0==c&&c*x|0==d)?d*x|0:-1
```

**Tests**:

```
console.log(s.apply(null,[14,24,34,44]), 54);
console.log(s.apply(null,[105,45,-15,-75]), -135);
console.log(s.apply(null,[5,25,125,625]), 3125);
console.log(s.apply(null,[256,64,16,4]), 1);

console.log(s.apply(null,[2,1,0,0]),0);
console.log(s.apply(null,[1,0,0,0]),0);
console.log(s.apply(null,[-325,-82,-21,-6]),-1);

console.log(s.apply(null,[-1,-1,-1,-1]),-1);
console.log(s.apply(null,[0,0,0,0]),0);
```

Works for them all.

Comment: Wasn't sure about the etiquette here. I know there's already another JS answer, but it doesn't address the edge cases. Mine is longer, but handles all those. Let me know if I didn't do this right.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with posting an answer in the same language as another answer, especially if your answer is correct and the other one is not. I don't know if you have enough rep to do so, but you might also want to comment on that answer to let them know which edge cases they are missing.

Comment: I actually took the edge cases from that other post, but they haven't solved the issue. ;P

Answer (score 2):

## GameMaker Language, 70 bytes

```
a=argument0;If a[3]+a[1]=a[2]*2return a[4]*2-a[3]return a[4]*a[4]/a[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>75 66 65</s> 61 bytes

```
lambda(a,b,c,d):d*2-c if d-c==b-a else d*b/a or b and d/(a/b)
```

Much longer than my previous 38 byte entry which did not cater for the division series correctly (just as most others didn't).

Test cases and more edge cases are on [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/lcrrk4)

*Note: integer division for a negative here is defined as having a remainder with the same sign as the divisor, so `-81/4` would be `-21` with a remainder of `3` and `-81/-4` would be `20` with a remainder of `-1`.*

Comment: negative number divided by negative number is positive... `-81/-4 != -21`

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Indeed it is. I have edited that and added the test case [325,-82,20,-5].

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>125</s> 123 bytes

Golfed:

```
int m(int[]a){int r=(a[1]>a[0])?a[1]/a[0]:a[0]/a[1];return(a[0]-a[1]==a[1]-a[2])?a[3]-a[0]+a[1]:(a[0]<a[1])?a[3]*r:a[3]/r;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
int m(int[] a)
{
    int r = (a[1] > a[0]) ? a[1] / a[0] : a[0] / a[1];
    return (a[0] - a[1] == a[1] - a[2]) ? a[3] - a[0] + a[1] : (a[0] < a[1]) ? a[3] * r : a[3] / r;
}
```

This code surely has some issues since it doesn't handle division by zero and such things. It also won't work of course if there are more (or less) than 4 integers in the input array `a`. Which makes it beyond stupid, but I had fun :)

Try it out: https://ideone.com/nELH5I

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 37 bytes

*Works on any TI-83/84 calculator*

```
Input L1                     gets input into an array
L1(4)²/L1(3                  calculate the fifth number in a geometric series
If not(sum(ΔList(ΔList(L1    if ΔList(ΔList(L1)) yields an array of all zeroes
L1(4)2-L1(3                  calculate the fifth number in an arithmetic series
                             Ans is implicitly returned
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
ṪḤ_ṪµṪ²:ṪµIE$?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlUPdyyJB1KHtoKITVZgpqeriv3///8NdIx0THTMAA)

```
ṪḤ_ṪµṪ²:ṪµIE$?  Main Link =
             ?  If
          IE$   [condition]
          I     The differences between consecutive elements
           E    Is equal
ṪḤ_Ṫ            [then]
Ṫ               The last element
 Ḥ              Doubled
  _             Minus
   Ṫ            The last element (second-last of original list)
    µṪ²:Ṫµ      [else]
     Ṫ          The last element
      ²         Squared
       :        Divided by
        Ṫ       The last element (second-last of original list)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 18 Bytes

```
?-+vzJEyQ/^E2J-yEJ
```

Accepts input as a newline-separated list of values.

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3F-%2BvzJEyQ%2F%5EE2J-yEJ&input=5%0A25%0A125%0A625&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
?                         If
 -                          the following are not equal:
  +vzJE                      the sum of first and third values (and call the third value J)
       yQ                    and the second value * 2;
                            (i.e. if it is not an additive or subtractive formula)
          ^E2             Then: square the fourth value
         /   J              and divide by the third
?                         Else:
               yE           double the fourth value
              -  J          and subtract the third
```