# Find Array Runs

Tags: code-golf, array

**Find the runs inside an array**

A run is defined as three or more numbers that increment from the previous with a constant step. For example `[1,2,3]` would be a run with step 1, `[1,3,5,7]` would be a run with step 2, and `[1,2,4,5]` is not a run.

We can express these runs by the notation `i to j by s` where `i` is the first number of the run, `j` is the last number of the run, and `s` is the step. However, runs of step 1 will be expressed `i to j`.

So using the arrays before, we get:

- `[1,2,3] -> "1to3"`
- `[1,3,5,7] -> "1to7by2"`
- `[1,2,4,5] -> "1 2 4 5"`

In this challenge, it is your task to do this for arrays that may have multiple runs.

**[Example Python code with recursion](https://tio.run/##hVNfb5swEH/nU9zah4BCJuimqorE3jZp2mulPURRZOAIVsBGZ7M0qvrZs8PQ1Chr54dD2Hf3@3N2d7K1Vl/O5xIrEES7QrfdjrAIRQzGCrI7qUp8itYB8LqF74KaE@CTtCBUCZzZk5FaAfJfp6WyLlFWfjVkGTSoQhGt0rHRsAhtT4rzKBSbVbqN3Ak279VeVS4WwcTqF2IHlkRxAF1BJclYKLGxAqyGQZIghGMtGwSDgopaqr0rdam7MTUDsfGAl@kWVvOtratpBHfP4JF6HHtoAglSAQm1x9DLjy@qPfJvYPIVQm4vpyx@TPiU@eTeyj0GP0RjcHaQE4rD5MnPCnhIzAlsTbrf1/xFR7bRuovhiKAQy8GhVhzYmJ494oo9WuNSHcof0Uwymdmws2atywzS4HVTsgR/Xt/Am/EtPNY49DXQav7amvncgerbHMlAjvaIqBycq0bjOzGbTub3HXv/Rii1WthRSH4arx1fhYGfnzpdmJvnF6ufX@DmM9vQChvOpxu7UUSwvHoJPKno0hDZ9fUH7fPT/yBiX9mHeHMsz02t@BlqhZOVwzQLtnZkElwTe4/QP9GjIOiIn3I4O9mkSZLEwPHOxa8u3rv4MMQ0YWVJFJ3PfwE)**

[IO is flexible](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

**Input**

Array of sorted positive ints (no duplicates)

**Output**

String of the runs separated by a space, or a string array of the runs

Does not need to be greedy in a particular direction

Can have trailing whitespace

**Test Cases**

```
In: [1000, 1002, 1004, 1006, 1008, 1010]
Out: "1000to1010by2"

In: [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233]
Out: "1to3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233"

In: [10, 20, 30, 40, 60]
Out: "10to40by10 60"

In: [5, 6, 8, 11, 15, 16, 17]
Out: "5 6 8 11 15to17"

In: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 30, 45, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 91, 93]
Out: "1to7 9to15by2 30 45 50to90by10 91 93"
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so least number of bytes wins.

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166177/get-the-sequence-steps)

Comment: Must it be greedy left-to-right? (i.e. can `[4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]` not be `4to6 7to15by2`?)

Comment: @JonathanAllan No, it does not necessarily need to be left greedy.

Comment: I suppose there will be no duplicate entries?

Comment: @user71546 Yes, no duplicates.

Comment: Is trailing whitespace acceptable?

Comment: Only Positive Integers. @Οurous Trailing whitespace acceptable.

Comment: Can we expect that the input will have length >1?(at least two integers)

Comment: @JayCe No, there could be an input of array size 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>42</s>  40 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen (filter out twos, `ḟ2`, rather than replacing twos with zeros, `2,0y`)

```
ŒṖIE×LƲ€ḟ2SƊÞṪµ.ịU,Iḟ1ƊQ€Fż“to“by”ṁṖƊ$)K
```

A full program printing the result.
(As a monadic Link a list containing a mixture of integers and characters would be yielded)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7p3m6Hp7uc2zTo6Y1D3fMNwo@1nV43sOdqw5t1Xu4uztUxxMoaHisKxAo7XZ0z6OGOSX5QCKp8lHD3Ic7G4Haj3WpaHr///8/2lRHwUxHwVxHwVJHwdAQiI2BGChobKCjYAKkTYG0GRCbA7EFEFuCMFCdpXEsAA)**
(Too inefficient for the largest test-case to complete within 60s, so I removed `[1,2,3,4]`.)

#### How?

```
ŒṖIE×LƲ€ḟ2SƊÞṪµ.ịU,Iḟ1ƊQ€Fż“to“by”ṁṖƊ$)K - Main Link: list of numbers
ŒṖ                                       - all partitions
           ƊÞ                            - sort by last three links as a monad:
      Ʋ€                                 -   last four links as a monad for €ach:
  I                                      -     incremental differences (of the part)
   E                                     -     all equal?
     L                                   -     length (of the part)
    ×                                    -     multiply
        ḟ2                               -   filter discard twos
          S                              -   sum
             Ṫ                           - tail (gets us the desired partition of the input)
              µ                       )  - perform this monadic chain for €ach:
               .                         -   literal 0.5
                ị                        -   index into (the part) - getting [tail,head]
                 U                       -   upend - getting [head,tail]
                      Ɗ                  -   last three links as a monad:
                   I                     -     incremental differences (of the part)
                     1                   -     literal one
                    ḟ                    -     filter discard (remove the ones)
                  ,                      -   pair -> [[head,tail],[deltasWithoutOnes]]
                       Q€                -   de-duplicate €ach -> [[head,tail],[delta]] or [[head,tail],[]] or [[loneValue],[]]
                         F               -   flatten -> [head,tail,delta] or [head,tail] or [loneValue]
                                     $   -   last two links as a monad:
                                    Ɗ    -     last three links as a monad:
                           “to“by”       -       literal list [['t', 'o'], ['b', 'y']]
                                   Ṗ     -       pop (get flattened result without rightmost entry)
                                  ṁ      -       mould ["to","by"] like that (i.e. ["to","by"] or ["to"] or [])
                         ż               -     zip together      
                                       K - join with spaces
                                         - implicit print
```

Comment: 'by' should not be used if step = 1

Comment: oh Gawwwd :p Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: `2,0ySƲÞ` can be golfed to `ḟ2SƊÞ` for -2 bytes.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen very true, nice golf, thanks

Comment: @KevinCruijssen FYI I remember why that was there now - originally I was trying to do my sorting with a product, `P`, rather than a sum `S` and would have needed the zeros.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah ok, that makes sense. In that case you'd indeed need the zeros. :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 6):

## Swift, 246 bytes

```
func f(_ a:[Int]){
var c=a.count,m=a+a,z=0,r:String=""
for i in 1..<c{m[i]-=a[i-1];if m[i]==m[i-1]{m[i-1]=0}};m[0]=1
for i in 0..<c{if m[i]==0 {z=1}else if z==0{r+=" \(a[i])"}else{r+="to\(a[i])"+(m[i]>1 ? "by\(m[i])":"");z=0;m[i+1]=1}}
print(r)
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7LboMwELzzFSufQDiRzSshqdtzzz0SVFEUV5YKqQhpVRDfTseGtlIPs/bOzszu9dPoPplnfWtr0v4zVYfise3LYPQ@qo5qVW3ry63teaOqsOKDErw7PPWdaV8VY56@dGTItCS327t6bApTblRVmI0sj0aT7ZVqXD8ujxLTdGwKUSr55xbO/WsQNA5KTue365lADmDGLlSMTj6yy4C5kaP6yw8X@tZ8L@mB2MvXyXUBOzAWHHE1VpoQ2@U0ee@4vve7wJs87RdSCMEJNXI1cTVzdW@rFGXgdJygiDmlnOwAvwhcDENqqRxcgiaK49WA2AiIgQTI1iCIsyUCdolO2m27f1sStwiTHad81caL3gXiTV0oFMAeyC2gy3HAPH8D)

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Very nice first answer. I hope you'll stay around because the Swift community here is... really small!

Comment: [This saves you a couple of bytes](https://tio.run/##ZU9BboMwELzzipVPIBxkAyEhxO25byAcKAqSpQIVIa0K4u10bKg49DBrz@zOrP341vUQL0v9bCuq3fKSv7VD4U1fZU@VKoOqe7YDb1Tpl3xUgveKMafuetKkW5JBcK2mJtfFQZW5Psgi0zUZrlRj@bQeSsxz1uSiUHJ3C@veDFc5jUrO94/HnSCN4L2vGN1cBBcesx0rDd2f5rvG@SLplb3/3Czx2IUxL8NTsU772Czn2fnsdTu4vTcv5ouUSyEEJ9TQ1tjWxNazqVIUnrONcsJQxOnIyfRwC6FF8ByNlEKLQcIo2j0ID4EIiIFkj4MlWYMQIsGkWXv6vy62G9E8cUq38Wi12FicRxuNCeAMpAaYS/GS5Rc)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 102 bytes

```
{1_,//${H:" ",h:*x;l:+/&\x=h+(!#x)*d:--/2#x;$[l>2;(H;"to";x l-1;(~d=1)#,"by",d;o l_x);l;H,o 1_x;""]}x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU9da8IwFH3frziLMlptaT5aa3Nxz/4HV3QizmExIHlIEf3r3U2FsadBOOTmnq@c88vXZRiO9qa2WVFMb2srILKTnQXq7Lx4@wir0zx5nYR0drB5XuhJoOmme9eUrEl4JyigyxUlj8NKpZNM7HuRHcih24aUOlpnDmobSIj2Hu6Dt7fppn9c7RGBdu5Mye74@d1RoJ6uaXt/8RslpQSDjlBGWERYMihJIq69i/d9r0UbBdAwqMAMA61gSlQ8NVBlCW0Ma7z7j/B0kdASRqKUWIw53pWcoeI4MiosooWCqqC4U03izxN3qv/U4Qje1WjGrYma6F2hin6oJZYSDR@F5tmQuexR8a9@md41zwYjS7TDDw)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 129 bytes

Returns an array of strings.

```javascript
a=>(a.map((n,i)=>n+[n-a[i+1]||''])+'').replace(/(\d+)(-\d+)(?:,\d+\2)+,(\d+)/g,(_,a,b,c)=>a+'to'+(~b?c+'by'+-b:c)).split(/-\d+,/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZHLasMwEEX3/QqRjSQkP@S3A0k@JAlFdpzg4lomMYVA6K@7V3JWTUtDDTOyhplzfcdv@kNf6nM7jF5vDs10XE16tWbaf9cDY71s@Wrdi23v6W0r1P52o3TPBaXcPzdDp@uGBWx3EJx5Lm@WEucu4kK6cnCS7FVqWckaIC3oaKhgn9WmFrS6UuFVy5pz/zJ07cgCy5ABn2rTX0zX@J05sSPbqjAMJUGOXE5czlwubFbhnnPy1BMEZGFxo7Fj1TVavHwXkwQysSSpJJaOtwi1GKqpLZWoJbhEcfyXqhMbTUxSUgAEDjCgAGIZFvEoD6cRIkYkiOx5bz97HU0CnyoE6UEMfrLZJRwq3JTdav4fRSuWkswaVUBhv/nvq03cdqGVS1Le1eP5C5xvnKnzjg5EgShtoK@ct35fbU5KKKX4jxjEHMZGU85@S4XmxfQF)

### How?

#### Step #1

We first append to each number a suffix consisting of a leading `'-'` followed by the difference with the next number, except for the last entry which is left unchanged. This new array is coerced to a string.

```javascript
(a.map((n, i) => n + [n - a[i + 1] || '']) + '')
```

Example:

```
Input : [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 11, 13, 20 ]
Output: "1-1,2-1,3-2,5-4,9-2,11-2,13-7,20"
```

#### Step #2

We identify all runs in the resulting string and replace them with the appropriate notation.

```javascript
.replace(
  /(\d+)(-\d+)(?:,\d+\2)+,(\d+)/g,
  (_, a, b, c) => a + 'to' + (~b ? c + 'by' + -b : c)
)
```

Example:

```
Input : "1-1,2-1,3-2,5-4,9-2,11-2,13-7,20"
Output: "1to3-2,5-4,9to13by2-7,20"
```

#### Step #3

Finally, we split the string on the remaining suffixes, including the trailing commas.

```javascript
.split(/-\d+,/)
```

Example:

```
Input : "1to3-2,5-4,9to13by2-7,20"
Output: [ '1to3', '5', '9to13by2', '20' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>125</s> 118 bytes

```ruby
->a{i=y=0;a.chunk{|x|-y+y=x}.map{|z,w|2-i<(s=w.size)?"#{w[i*s]}to#{w[~i=0]}"+"by#{z}"*(z<=>1)+' ':' '*i+w*' '*i=1}*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDLboMwELznKyxyIAGDbAwktHH6IcgHEiWKVTWJCoin@@t07PTSw8zujmdnJX@3p2G5yiU6VpOWg2TvVXy@tffPae7naAgH2Zv4q3pO80i7OYn0YVPLLq71eNl@eOupK3VQK9M8bPujJVPGC73TsJ5G4wWb8SCPfBv6xH8DAh12gauSm8D3zdLIclVyxhgl4MRx6jh3vLfMmaJwUYJ3QUlGiZXRJdAE7JmVCmgphkQIZ0dkAgggBXIXAmP@Wscqx8Ttnd2//NSdgL6jpPhzipfbhaFmLhAOYA8UFvAVQq1UfKnON/t9z7apybXslVl@AQ)

#### Explanation

Ruby's Enumerable has a useful `chunk` method that does precisely what we need here - it groups items by consecutive runs of the same return value from the block, in our case - the difference between the current (`x`) and previous (`y`) value.

The caveat is that such strategy won't capture the first element of the run, e.g. here only the two last elements are grouped together:

```ruby
Input: [5, 6, 8, 11, 15, 16, 17]
Grouped: [[5, [5]], [1, [6]], [2, [8]], [3, [11]], [4, [15]], [1, [16, 17]]]
```

Therefore, while mapping to the correctly formatted strings, when we encounter a new potential run (chunk with > 1 item), we must track if the previous item was single (`i=1`) or already used in another run (`i=0`). If there is an unused single item, it becomes the starting point of the run, and lowers the chunk size threshold from 3 to 2.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>238</s> 217 bytes

Thanks @digEmAll for -19 bytes.

```r
function(v,R=rle(diff(v)),L=R$l,S=sum(L|1),Y=0)if(!S)cat(v)else for(i in 1:S){D=R$v[i]
N=L[i]-F
if(N>1){N=N+1
cat(v[Y+1],'to',v[Y+N],'by'[D>1],D[D>1],' ',sep='')
F=1}else{N=N+(i==S)
if(N>0)cat(v[Y+1:N],'')
F=0}
Y=Y+N}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHLbsIwELznK1xaKV5hJDsJj9CaE@KEciAnRDm0NK4spQGRgFRRvj0dO1UPRT3M7Ho1M7uSj615GrTmVO0au6/4Waz0sSz4mzWGn4nEUq8eSpHr@vTBl1@KxFpLsobf5bR7aSApyrpgZn/kltmKqWlOlzk8543dBpleogwWAQzZTNEl01lfBd64WffVVoTNPhSuz9C/foab@QzTeVdCFoq6OOgwpGCh1dWt8hHcap1TlyrpN27qQrxWXoO1Rui1NXzHlZRSMHDkOfE88jxxrCTRo0vpPVc9CrxFMIhjwYaCOQ26CLMY3qEbpZgleERxfOvFsgiIgQQY3cYjYtQFI1Thpdw54//PSPwlEI0FS39scWf1a1CHfhUUwARIHaBL/16YErtnta3eywJfdjg17Tc)

Comment: use `F` instead of `n` as it's already initialized to `0`, which should save a few bytes, I think.

Comment: This one is frustrating. You're nearly there by just using `split`, `diff` and `rle`. Unfortunately, the greedy search for runs means a lot of fiddling.

Comment: [214 bytes](https://tio.run/##dU5Na8JAFLznVyxS2F18Qr78iHU9ifHgyXhLc2jTbLsQYtE0UMTfns6ueijSw8z7YGbeO/Z6Mer1d1O25tCIjnbqWFfi3WgtOilpo@qq@Wg/5VkfjsIw07BgvhG7p1rK81ah5qbwVmg626TqVLXOvB/68y2tpZepjUilZ7TIlqEsX1vR5WmRBwXx9sDJDRmGtx@er5ZYr66FM06n6ktxLqv6VJ0RYBa3y6lK81FWePc0gujirVUp1oRbe7Ufbi@XXotSBL7vEwOHjmPHE8czy4Ev5bPNGbw0A@k5CzGII2JjYlaDLsQugndsVwl2MYYwih69OBYCERADk8d4REyuwQgNMAX2nen/b8TuE4imxJKbLbpa3RnUsTsFBTADEgvokr8f9r8 "R – Try It Online") Almost there, the only problem is the uncorrect spacing sometimes...

Comment: That `'by'[D>1]` is a good trick.

Comment: This seems to work fine [217 bytes](https://tio.run/##dVHLbsIwELznK1xaKV5hJDsJj9CaE@KEciAnRDm0NK4spQGRgFRRvj0dO1UPRT3M7Ho1M7uSj615GrTmVO0au6/4Waz0sSz4mzWGn4nEUq8eSpHr@vTBl1@KxFpLsobf5bR7aSApyrpgZn/kltmKqWlOlzk8543dBpleogwWAQzZTNEl01lfBd64WffVVoTNPhSuz9C/foab@QzTeVdCFoq6OOgwpGCh1dWt8hHcap1TlyrpN27qQrxWXoO1Rui1NXzHlZRSMHDkOfE88jxxrCTRo0vpPVc9CrxFMIhjwYaCOQ26CLMY3qEbpZgleERxfOvFsgiIgQQY3cYjYtQFI1Thpdw54//PSPwlEI0FS39scWf1a1CHfhUUwARIHaBL/16YErtnta3eywJfdjg17Tc "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @digEmAll Does one need to handle single input? Otherwise dropping the first chars of the function brings us to 200 bytes flush.

Comment: @JayCe: the question doesn't specified that, but I assumed it needs to since the input is defined as "an array of positive ints". Maybe we can ask...

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>180</s> 175 bytes

```r
r=rle(c(0,diff(a<-scan())));for(j in 1:sum(1|r$l)){l=r$l[j];v=r$v[j];i=T+l-1;cat("if"(l>2-F,paste0(a[T][!F],"to",a[i],"by"[v>1],v[v>1]," "),c("",a[T:i])[-3^F]));T=i+1;F=l<3-F}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nU/RaoQwEHzvV0xzfYicQtYYPfW8R7/AN7GQWoUc9q6oFUrbb79uWvoDDcvsLLMzbObbrhmWFb1dhqW425FSCgyxh8RD6uHAQIplxNAw4FkjJugEhqcclCSItfYBiBW0QqKQssMg9dsEMiDOyv5C2MlShvxH1F73LgPjjcgUDgo5FyHXt7map0H2UoXPbhylPUZLby8y4FeO11me4S6gYnl7kfQ5P0xB8DFV3NtzV25MNk9c1eyniMrerlK4UcjpFEd1@GqXdVDStk3X3tddKNarCG3rmD29i3Y7URduv01ABGEvhdebwnVBG@nHuuMjmsrtqayr6aij@uv2nz9@Aw)

Conceptually, this is a port of my [Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171287/78274), though obviously quite a bit different technically.

5 bytes saved by JayCe.

Comment: I wanted to to something with `rle` but was too lazy... you can save 1 byte doing `sum(1|x)` in place of `length(x)`: [TIO](https://tio.run/##nU/LboMwELz3K6ZOD0YByYt5BAg58gXcEJUcCpIjmlRAkaq2307XqfoDXVmzs5qdkXfadnU/L@jM3M/5w46UUmAIHUQOEgcHBlIsI4RGDJ41QoKOEPOUgaIIodYuAKGCVogUEnbESNw2gWIQZ6V/IexkKUV2F7XTnStG7IxIFQ4KGT9CprepnMZedlL5L3YYpDkGc2eu0uMqhtskL7BXUD6/v0r6mp5Gz/scS@7NpS1WJqsjtqz3Y0CFsIOQ4ykMKr8zizRN3TaPVeuL5SZ801hm5w/RrCdq/fW3CQh/7t9KIby7p5PCrda5bb0m0M9Vyx@pS7unoirHow6q7@0/d/4A)

Comment: Actually you can have just 1 `cat ` for 175 bytes: [TIO](https://tio.run/##nU/RaoQwEHzvV0xzfYicQtYYPfW8R7/AN7GQWoUc9q6oFUrbb79uWvoDDcvsLLMzbObbrhmWFb1dhqW425FSCgyxh8RD6uHAQIplxNAw4FkjJugEhqcclCSItfYBiBW0QqKQssMg9dsEMiDOyv5C2MlShvxH1F73LgPjjcgUDgo5FyHXt7map0H2UoXPbhylPUZLby8y4FeO11me4S6gYnl7kfQ5P0xB8DFV3NtzV25MNk9c1eyniMrerlK4UcjpFEd1@GqXdVDStk3X3tddKNarCG3rmD29i3Y7URduv01ABGEvhdebwnVBG@nHuuMjmsrtqayr6aij@uv2nz9@Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>208</s> ... 185 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Data.List,Text
l=length
$[]=""
$k=last[u<+(if(v>[])("to"<+last v<+if(u<v!!0-1)("by"<+(v!!0-u))"")"")+" "+ $t\\i=:[u:v]<-inits k&t<-tails k|l(nub(zipWith(-)i v))<2&&l i<>2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5Ba8JAEIXv/opxCWFDNsWYqlU2nuyh4KFgoYeYwxqjDm42Yiahlv72xrGFebx575vDFLY0rq/qfWtLqAy6HqtLfSXY0P7VdWplyDytsSH1UX7RwKa2dEc6DbwsT4UYeOfUmoayVocSD7JbZnkgBdVCh48eOh1y3epuOBxFMaPdjZH8i20QCPGYUIAIwaPtFtNF1i66XEfokBo4@6QjMmh5/bHStTv5jZdPpJOMAoQuCPTY9y2gXo7zfkOGH0/BgyxWMFaQKHhWMFEwVTBTMFcQM4i5jrlMRozZJ@xT1oz1wpo/xHfzJO9/i4M1x6aP3tb96uZMhcV/eLeGDvW1ugM)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>177</s> 173 bytes

```javascript
a=>{for(h=t=p=d=0,o=[];(c=a[t])||h<t;p=c,t++)d||!c?c-p!=d?(o.push(...[[a[h]+"to"+p+(d>1?"by"+d:"")],[p],[p-d,p]][t-h<3?t-h:0]),d=0,h=t--):0:!d&&t-h?d=c-p:0;return o.join` `}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU7BjoMgFLzvV1APDQY0KNpWLfVDCEmt2LVNI8TSTTbrfrv7sHvbZg8zwGPmzVybj@bejhfrosHobj6LuRGHr7MZcS@csEILRo2QqsKtaKRT4TT1e1dZ0VJHSKinadXWbWRXQtfYxPZx73Ecx1I2slckcCYglmB9SOrg9BkQXQZBqKi0HpGmVinpon7Pa@CSqZD6QIiOorBk5Uqv1/BRawERJavGzj3GAZn4ai7DER2/56o1w93cuvhm3vEZy4QxRhFwunC28GbhnecEMsK3Py6KQM8pyinyMrilMONgz/2ogFkGj5Tzl3aITAEckAE2L0Ng0ea5HlYn8Ep8r@2/fbKlEui2FBW/Tv50L2Fw5ksgKAA7QOEBusJXnX8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>170</s> 166 bytes

```python
def f(a):
 j=len(a)
 while j>2:
	l,r=a[:j:j-1];s=(r-l)/~-j
	if a[:j]==range(l,r+1,s):return[`l`+'to%d'%r+'by%d'%s*(s>1)]+f(a[j:])
	j-=1
 return a and[`a[0]`]+f(a[1:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU5BboMwEDzHr9hLBBSjYgwkuCIfQUhQAQ0WIpGhqnLp1@nYVKoi9TDj3fXM7N4f6/U2J9vW9QMNfhsoRrqc@hklo6/rOPWkL4lih4mbsq2UVjoS9dtS@iaagtfvSLPDOJD9qcvStPNH70MaCr4EyvTrp5mrZmpCb70dO@9oQu/9YYvlxV8uIqhDLK20qgN20FEpGO0eaqmdu6ppq7hudpGAaLubcV5xaCXiOOYEThynjnPHZ8siRiT7k3OCUHLKONl/VAlmEr7MjgrMUjSJlM8@LEkACaRA/hwLa74HIkygE/aE0/@rU7cdghOn4tcid5uLx5u5FVAAZ6CwgK7AVdsP)

Comment: I'm not sure if this output format is valid; the runs should all be strings, no?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Fixed

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 41 bytes

```
ŒṖIE€Ạ$>Ẉ2eƊƲƇṪµ.ịṚj⁾to;IḢ⁾by;ẋ⁻1$ƲƊµḊ¡€K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7p3m6Pmpa83DXAhW7h7s6jFKPdR3bdKz94c5Vh7bqPdzd/XDnrKxHjftK8q09H@5YBGQlVVo/3NX9qHG3oQpQYdehrQ93dB1aCDTC@////9GGBjoKRkBsDMQmQGxmEAsA)

Full program.

Answer (score 1):

## [gvm](https://github.com/Zirias/gvm) (commit [2612106](https://github.com/Zirias/gvm/commit/26121066d5955d1b1e11ee8e34715f8ac5d60fc2)) bytecode, 108 bytes

Expects the size of the array in one line, then the members each in one line.

Hexdump:

```
> hexdump -C findruns.bin
00000000  e1 0a 00 10 00 e1 0b 00  ff c8 92 00 f4 f7 10 00  |................|
00000010  01 b0 20 03 00 ff 0a 01  a2 01 c8 92 00 f4 01 c0  |.. .............|
00000020  03 00 ff 0a 02 d0 72 01  0a 03 c8 92 00 f4 05 b0  |......r.........|
00000030  20 a2 02 c0 02 02 6a 03  8b 00 ff f6 06 b0 20 a2  | .....j....... .|
00000040  02 f4 ce 0a 02 c8 92 00  f6 07 6a 03 8b 00 ff f6  |..........j.....|
00000050  f2 b9 66 01 a2 02 00 01  8a 03 f6 05 b9 69 01 a2  |..f..........i..|
00000060  03 92 00 f4 ac c0 74 6f  00 62 79 00              |......to.by.|
0000006c
```

Test runs:

```
> echo -e "7\n5\n6\n8\n11\n15\n16\n17\n" | ./gvm findruns.bin
5 6 8 11 15to17
> echo -e "20\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n9\n11\n13\n15\n30\n45\n50\n60\n70\n80\n90\n91\n93\n" | ./gvm findruns.bin
1to7 9to15by2 30 45 50to90by10 91 93
```

Manually assembled from this:

```
0100  e1        rud                     ; read length of array
0101  0a 00     sta     $00             ; -> to $00
0103  10 00     ldx     #$00            ; loop counter
                  readloop:
0105  e1        rud                     ; read unsigned number
0106  0b 00 ff  sta     $ff00,x         ; store in array at ff00
0109  c8        inx                     ; next index
010a  92 00     cpx     $00             ; length reached?
010c  f4 f7     bne     readloop        ; no -> read next number
010e  10 00     ldx     #$00            ; loop counter
0110  01                                ; 'lda $20b0', to skip next instruction
                  runloop:
0111  b0 20     wch     #' '            ; write space character
0113  03 00 ff  lda     $ff00,x         ; load next number from array
0116  0a 01     sta     $01             ; -> to $01
0118  a2 01     wud     $01             ; and output
011a  c8        inx                     ; next index
011b  92 00     cpx     $00             ; length reached?
011d  f4 01     bne     compare         ; if not calculate difference
011f  c0        hlt                     ; done
                  compare:
0120  03 00 ff  lda     $ff00,x         ; load next number from array
0123  0a 02     sta     $02             ; -> to $01
0125  d0        sec                     ; calculate ...
0126  72 01     sbc     $01             ; ... difference ...
0128  0a 03     sta     $03             ; ... to $03
012a  c8        inx                     ; next index
012b  92 00     cpx     $00             ; length reached?
012d  f4 05     bne     checkrun        ; if not check whether we have a run
012f  b0 20     wch     #' '            ; output space
0131  a2 02     wud     $02             ; output number
0133  c0        hlt                     ; done
                  checkrun:
0134  02 02     lda     $02             ; calculate next ...
0136  6a 03     adc     $03             ; ... expected number in run
0138  8b 00 ff  cmp     $ff00,x         ; compare with real next number
013b  f6 06     beq     haverun         ; ok -> found a run
013d  b0 20     wch     #' '            ; otherwise output space ...
013f  a2 02     wud     $02             ; ... and number
0141  f4 ce     bne     runloop         ; and repeat searching for runs
                  haverun:
0143  0a 02     sta     $02             ; store number to $02
0145  c8        inx                     ; next index
0146  92 00     cpx     $00             ; length reached?
0148  f6 07     beq     outputrun       ; yes -> output this run
014a  6a 03     adc     $03             ; calculate next expected number
014c  8b 00 ff  cmp     $ff00,x         ; compare with real next number
014f  f6 f2     beq     haverun         ; ok -> continue parsing run
                  outputrun:
0151  b9 66 01  wtx     str_to          ; write "to"
0154  a2 02     wud     $02             ; write end number of run
0156  00 01     lda     #$01            ; compare #1 with ...
0158  8a 03     cmp     $03             ; ... step size
015a  f6 05     beq     skip_by         ; equal, then skip output of "by"
015c  b9 69 01  wtx     str_by          ; output "by"
015f  a2 03     wud     $03             ; output step size
                  skip_by:
0161  92 00     cpx     $00             ; length of array reached?
0163  f4 ac     bne     runloop         ; no -> repeat searching for runs
0165  c0        hlt                     ; done
                  str_to:
0166  74 6f 00                          ; "to"
                  str_by:
0169  62 79 00                          ; "by"
016c
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>138</s> 136 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer).

```python
r=[];d=0
for n in input()+[0]:
 a=n-([n]+r)[-1]
 if(a-d)*d:
	if r[2:]:r=["%dto"%r[0]+`r[-1]`+"by%s"%d*(1%d)]
	print r.pop(0),
 r+=n,;d=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7baoQwFHzefMVBELzEkou6q8UvCYG1q1JfoqQWul9vJ9k@FDKTnDlzJmd/Hp@bU@djm@YhSZLTD8a@T4Ngy@bJ0RrO/n1keWmE7RmNg6sy42zpc1NJy2hdsrGa8mLq2WVdyBvV2x4pSTodW5J6jJV3H7z3Mvl4pl9oFJlMp9yyy@5Xd5B/27c9Ezln5MvBcfw/nrHFsBKbf@YHhQWL5jRSCMEJrCLXkdvIt8BSWGYkJ7Q1p4ZTUPFS0DTcTZA6aDUKpXVwI1ABGqiBNkTA1r6GMShRyfDJ9X94HfMhXzl1f0b9Msco3E2MgwO4AV0AfJ22vw)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>49</s> 50 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.œʒε¥Ë}P}Σ€g2KO>}¤εD©g≠i¬s¤„toý¬®¥0èDU≠i„byX««]˜ðý
```

Way too long, but I'm already glad it's working. This challenge is a lot harder than it looks imo.. Can without a doubt be golfed further.
`Σ€g2KO>}¤` is a port of `2,0ySƲÞṪ` [from *@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171266/52210) (thanks!).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AXoAhf8wNWFiMWX//y7Fk8qSzrXCpcOLfVB9zqPigqxnMktPPn3CpM61RMKpZ@KJoGnCrHPCpOKAnnRvw73CrMKuwqUww6hEVeKJoGnigJ5ieVjCq8KrXcucw7DDvf//WzEsMiwzLDExLDE4LDIwLDIyLDI0LDMyLDMzLDM0XQ) (NOTE: Times out for the big test cases.)

+1 byte as bug-fix because `0` is always put at a trailing position when sorting.

**Explanation:**

```python
.œ                       # Get all partions of the (implicit) input-list
                         #  i.e. [1,2,3,11,18,20,22,24,32,33,34]
                         #   → [[[1],[2],[3],[11],[18],[20],[22],[24],[32],[33],[34]],
                         #      [[1],[2],[3],[11],[18],[20],[22],[24],[32],[33,34]],
                         #      [[1],[2],[3],[11],[18],[20],[22],[24],[32,33],[34]],
                         #      ...]
  ʒ     }                # Filter this list by:
   ε  }                  #  Map the current sub-list by:
    ¥Ë                   #   Take the deltas, and check if all are equal
                         #    i.e. [1,2,3] → [1,1] → 1
                         #    i.e. [1,2,3,11] → [1,1,8] → 0
       P                 #  Check if all sub-list have equal deltas
  Σ      }               # Now that we've filtered the list, sort it by:
   €g                    #  Take the length of each sub-list
                         #   i.e. [[1,2,3],[11,18],[20,22,24],[32,33],[34]]
                         #    → [3,2,3,2,1]
                         #   i.e. [[1,2,3],[11],[18,20,22,24],[32,33,34]]
                         #    → [3,1,4,3]
     2K                  #  Remove all 2s
                         #   i.e. [3,2,3,2,1] → ['3','3','1']
       O                 #  And take the sum
                         #   i.e. ['3','3','1'] → 7
                         #   i.e. [3,1,4,3] → 11
        >                #  And increase the sum by 1 (0 is always trailing when sorting)
          ¤              # And then take the last item of this sorted list
                         #  i.e. for input [1,2,3,11,18,20,22,24,32,33,34]
                         #   → [[1,2,3],[11],[18,20,22,24],[32,33,34]]
  ε                      # Now map each of the sub-lists to:
   D©                    #  Save the current sub-list in the register
     g≠i                 #  If its length is not 1:
                         #    i.e. [11] → 1 → 0 (falsey)
                         #    i.e. [18,20,22,24] → 4 → 1 (truthy)
        ¬s¤              #   Take the head and tail of the sub-list
                         #    i.e. [18,20,22,24] → 18 and 24
           „toý          #   And join them with "to"
                         #    i.e. 18 and 24 → ['18to24', '18to20to22to24']
               ¬         #   (head to remove some access waste we no longer need)
                         #    i.e. ['18to24', '18to20to22to24'] → '18to24'
        ®                #   Get the sub-list from the register again
         ¥               #   Take its deltas
                         #    i.e. [18,20,22,24] → [2,2,2]
          0è             #   Get the first item (should all be the same delta)
                         #    i.e. [2,2,2] → 2
            DU           #   Save it in variable `X`
              ≠i         #   If the delta is not 1:
                         #     i.e. 2 → 1 (truthy)
                „byX«    #    Merge "by" with `X`
                         #     i.e. 2 → 'by2'
                     «   #    And merge it with the earlier "#to#"
                         #     i.e. '18to24' and 'by2' → '18to24by2'
                      ]  # Close the mapping and both if-statements
˜                        # Flatten the list
                         #  i.e. ['1to3',[11],'18to24by2','32to34']
                         #   → ['1to3',11,'18to24by2','32to34']
 ðý                      # And join by spaces (which we implicitly output as result)
                         #  i.e. ['1to3',11,'18to24by2','32to34']
                         #   → '1to3 11 18to24by2 32to34'
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 154 bytes

```perl
{my(@r,$r);@r&&(@$r<2||$$r[1]-$$r[0]==$_-$$r[-1])?push@$r,$_:push@r,$r=[$_]for@_;join" ",map@$_<3?@$_:("$$_[0]to$$_[-1]by".($$_[1]-$$_[0]))=~s/by1$//r,@r}
```

Same with spaces, newlines, #comments and `sub by`:

```perl
sub by {
  my(@r,$r);
  @r &&                               # if at least one run candidate exists and...
   ( @$r<2                            # ...just one elem so far
     || $$r[1]-$$r[0] == $_-$$r[-1] ) # ...or diff is same
    ? push @$r, $_                    # then add elem to curr. run candidate
    : push @r, $r=[$_]                # else start new run cand. with curr elem
        for @_;
  join " ",
    map @$_<3                                         # is it a run?
    ? @$_                                             # no, just output the numbers
    : ("$$_[0]to$$_[-1]by".($$_[1]-$$_[0]))=~s/by1$//r, # yes, make run, delete by1
    @r                                                # loop run candidates
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDBbqMwEL3zFZblVhA5AUNIQggbKvWyl@2lt4CsZZdms20wC460KM3@evbZSatKPcx4PH7vzRu3dfcSn/tDRarhfNwPbt5x1nlp3t3eujnrVuHrK2PdRpRjcwRlljFpy7EovXV76H8BxZlc2tKQsw2T5ZPqcpn@VruGEsr339ucyVW0Rl66lDEJJa3MCZlqoBPX1HaIefK87F/vV4Ngvt/xvDud9wPJdd3rDFJHv9i4k5FXlJMRNQX1@3TTty877fpFP@IInzPhcRaWJ9v3i6ZofG79UL66v3u8@5I6MOlaVe/oEIIRrM5aZaym1/s2q/AlTHqm0Xa7Rj/Rm/GsJzfjOOwJIfXftv6h659LdKJ5T7ZKX8uiodxlNan/QGZNH57pkn5Tmqhn6lkjrvkZo81Zzdk2dU6OlMaZlM7XZkk2IggCTpBDm6c2z2xemCyC0nk4YB41SK1MpxpC6lzpnIAYcRJzYvCoQvQi6MSmlaA3xSWMoncdrSISkwXAwAIKJIAGZ2DvyrAVIiLEFDH7YESrKUyIAM03OIbNLhYwXuAmzBLzN05MZmaiwBN2mH@yP7UbgDLnJLmKRBchawBnbE0AgVggEhPAJR83m5ME@jF@CDzQwNIquZhNBLD0/B8)

...for passing tests from OP.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 77 bytes

```
\d+
$*
(1+)(?= \1(1+))
$1:$2
1:(1+) (1+:\1 )+(1+)
1to$3by$1
:1+|by1\b

1+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxLCsJAEET3fYpaDJIYkK7pmfxAvEg2Bl24URA3gneP3SIMj3lUVz2vr9v9vG3LpZO0l4Zd25yOWBi/VhLnlIVzGBzzQrRdmPD1SLa@E2Vm91nfXFYR@spht21UVThyoAT6wOigCpFhqHA1ZMIKqtsEloJsJlRkhSmKolep6OOWYAV9aPgveM2TAdMvs4ijU1GjhkExKiZ/xGRf) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
(1+)(?= \1(1+))
$1:$2
```

Compute consecutive differences.

```
1:(1+) (1+:\1 )+(1+)
1to$3by$1
```

Convert runs to `to...by` syntax.

```
:1+|by1\b
```

Remove unconverted differences and `by1`.

```
1+
$.&
```

Convert to decimal.