# Find the pattern

Tags: code-golf, math

I feel tired to do "find the pattern" exercise such as

```
1 2 3 4 (5)
1 2 4 8 (16)
1 2 3 5 8 (13)
```

Please write a program that finds the pattern for me.

Here, we define the pattern as a recurrence relation that fits the given input, with the smallest score. If there are multiple answers with the same smallest score, using any one is fine.

Let the \$k\$ first terms be initial terms (for the recurrence relation, etc.), and the \$i\$'th term be \$f(i)\$ (\$i>k,i\in\mathbb N\$).

- A non-negative integer \$x\$ adds\$\lfloor\log_2\max(|x|,1)\rfloor+1\$  to the score
- The current index \$i\$ adds \$1\$ to the score
- `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` (round down or towards zero, as you decide) and `mod` (`a mod b` always equal to `a-b*(a/b)`) each add \$1\$ to the score
- For each initial term \$x\$, add \$\lfloor\log_2\max(|x|,1)\rfloor+2\$  to the score
- \$f(i-n)\$ (with \$n\le k\$) adds \$n\$ to the score. E.g. Using the latest value \$f(i-1)\$ add \$1\$ to the score, and there must be at least 1 initial term.
- Changing the calculation order doesn't add anything to the score. It's fine if you write `1+i` as `1 i +`, `+(i,1)` or any format you like.

Samples:

```
input   -> [score]    expression
1 2 3 4     -> [1]    f(i) = i
1 2 4 8     -> [5]    f(1) = 1, f(i) = f(i-1)+f(i-1)
1 2 3 5 8   -> [9]    f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(i) = f(i-1)+f(i-2)
```

Shortest program in each language wins. It's fine if your program only solve the problem theoretically.

Comment: Should `1, 2, 4, 8` be `f(1) = 1, f(i) = f(i - 1) + f(i - 1)`? And how current score 5 got?

Comment: `f(1) = 1` is 2 points, `f(2) = 2` is 3 points, `f(i-1)` is 1 point, `+` is 1 point, `f(i-2)` is 2 points. So `f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(i) = f(i-1) + f(i-2)` is 9 points. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @tsh Fixed issues. Data generated by hand

Comment: +1 how is the `1,2,4,8` scored at `5`? I see an "initial term x" of `1` adding two, "the current index i" twice adding one each, "two non-negative integer x" both with value `1` each adding one, and a `+`adding one. This makes seven, but I could easily be misinterpreting something.

Comment: @JonathanAllan The `1` in `f(i-1)` doesn't count as integer itself

Comment: Ahh "f(i−n)  (with n≤k) adds n to the score". This is all quite hard to follow :D Might be worth showing the scoring of some examples.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Also note that `f` cannot be used directly in the expression of `f`, except as `f(i-n)`. (for example `f(i÷2)` cannot be used)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What comes next?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3485/what-comes-next)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 554 bytes

```python
lambda s:next((s[:i],x)for n in N()for i in R(A(s))if(b:=sum(map(lambda k:A(bin(abs(k)))-1,s[:i])))<n for x in X(n-b,i)if all(E(s,x,j)==s[j]for j in R(i,A(s))))
E=lambda s,x,i:x if int==type(x)else i+1if"i"==x else s[i-x[1]]if"@"==x[0]else.5if(r:=E(s,x[2],i))==0else[(l:=E(s,x[1],i))+r,l-r,l*r,l//r,l%r]["+-*/%".index(x[0])]
A=len
R=range
def X(k,i):
 for x in["i",0]*(k==1)+[["@",k]]*(k<=i)+[[op,l,r]for a in R(1,k-1)for r in X(k-a-1,i)for l in X(a,i)for op in"+-*/%"if k>2]:yield x
 for n in R(2**(k-1),2**k):yield n
def N(k=0):
 while 1>0:k+=1;yield k
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZLBatwwEIahRz-FWQhI9jhreZOQulHoHpJjDjkVVB1sVk600mqN7VDvs_SyUNp3ap-mI2kTCDnIHn0a_vn12z__9Ifpee-Ov-75998vU1dc__uU2WbXbpp0rJ2aJ0JGUWsJM-32Q-pS7dIHEmrt60eyJiOluiNtzceXHdk1PTkJmHpNWu1I047EUEoLBkELyxuXeonZS3wjrmhBo0baWEvuyAgzbCnno9hK37WNgzSEUZQmd_zVInbqGlU6bJk4nw69IjNVdlSpzpnuFnrB-ZwGMApdzIJJifirx6KU_uD8Et0PNQ-DRSXRCg4v_ZEg9pWzwPMBbIErw7Vc4uNskGKRF9nybHGu3UbNxMtSmay5VS555EPjnlSyUR3e06BEnbzdXKA7KGVGDOeM5kKgLTDSgxuuPdj3YGEIITQxBAamYCH-IWZnigZz1QHZiJrTdt_j_mQOEzK3lawPWtlNOkcTLmpWGU5EVcDC0FOLC54f0FvpPf941lal7LasTc7Zl9hj4i_z96kfMH5yTwSDClZwgZ84eccu4PoDW8HlB7qCK2DlO-jRZ2AVwjjueIzv_w)

*running the test-cases takes approximately 30 seconds*

*The running time is at exponential in the score, so the program may take extremely long to finish if the sequence has a score of more than 10*

Output format:

1. array of initial values
2. expression for remaining values

- `i`: index, integers -> constants
- `["@",k]` -> `f(i-k)` (for k any integer)
- `[op,l,r]` -> `l op r` (l,r expressions; op operation)

Uses `%` for mod (I can change it if it is a problem)

for example: `([1, 1], ['+', ['@', 1], ['@', 2]])` -> `f(1)=f(2)=1, f(i)=f(i-1)+f(i-2)`

### Explanation

Go through all expressions in order of score

`expressions(k,i)` (golfed: `X`) generates all expressions with score `k` and `i` initial elements

`check` and `evaluate` (golfed: in-lined/`E`) evaluate the expression to check if it generates the sequence

The main function goes through all expressions ordered by score and returns the first expression that computes the sequence.

ungolfed version:

```
def evaluate(seq,expr,i):
 if type(expr)==int:
  return expr
 if expr=="i":
  return i+1
 if expr[0]=="@":
  return seq[i-expr[1]]
 if expr[0]=="+":
  return evaluate(seq,expr[1],i)+evaluate(seq,expr[2],i)
 if expr[0]=="-":
  return evaluate(seq,expr[1],i)-evaluate(seq,expr[2],i)
 if expr[0]=="*":
  return evaluate(seq,expr[1],i)*evaluate(seq,expr[2],i)
 if expr[0]=="/":
  return evaluate(seq,expr[1],i)//evaluate(seq,expr[2],i)
 if expr[0]=="%":
  return evaluate(seq,expr[1],i)%evaluate(seq,expr[2],i)

def check(seq,n_initTerms,expr): ## check if expr is an expression for this sequence
 try:
  for i in range(n_initTerms,len(seq)):
   if not evaluate(seq,expr,i)==seq[i]:
    return False
  return True
 except:
  return False

def expressions(k,i):
 if k==1:
  yield "i"
 if k<=i:
  yield ["@",k]
 if k>2:
  for a in range(1,k-1):
   for op in "+-*/%":
    for l in expressions(a,i):
     for r in expressions(k-a-1,i):
      yield [op,l,r]
 for n in range(2**(k-1),2**k):
  yield n
 if k==1:
  yield 0

def find(seq):
 n=1;
 while True:
  for i in range(len(seq)-1):
   base_score=sum(map(lambda k:len(bin(abs(k)))-2,seq[:i]))
   if base_score<n:
    for expr in expressions(n-base_score,i):
     if check(seq,i,expr):
      return (seq[:i],expr)
  n+=1
```

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 613 bytes

```python
lambda s:min((sum(map(L,s[:i]))+S(s,x),k,s[:i],x)for k in range(2**sum(map(L,s)))if all(E(s,x:=B(k//A(s),i:=k%A(s)),j)==s[j]for j in range(k%A(s),A(s))))[2:]
I=int
A=len
L=lambda k:A(bin(abs(k)))-1
S=lambda s,x:L(x)-1if I==type(x)else 1if"i"==x else x[1]if"@"==x[0]else S(s,x[1])+S(s,x[2])+1
E=lambda s,x,i:x if I==type(x)else i+1if"i"==x else s[i-x[1]]if"@"==x[0]else.5if(r:=E(s,x[2],i))==0else[(l:=E(s,x[1],i))+r,l-r,l*r,l//r,l%r]["+-*/%".index(x[0])]
B=lambda k,i:[q:=(k-i)//3,"i"if k==0else["@",k]if k<=i else[q,-q][r]if(r:=(k-1)%3)<2else["+-*/%"[q%5],B(I((r:=bin(q//5))[2::2],2),i),B(I("0"+r[3::2],2),i)]][1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZLPauMwEMahRz-FMRhG8biK7Wbpigo2gRQCufWo1cGhTleR48Z2Cu6z7CVQ2nfafZod2cn2Tw6ypZ9G33yj0e-33fP-12N1eLmVP1-f9uv4-u9FUebb1X3ut2JrKoD2aQvbfAdLbJUwmrHoDlrsGNoB0HT92PjWN5Xf5NVDAelo9OEQY8ys_bwsYe7OCTkDy_kUWoZGSBu6GcMNk7JVG-2kNu9Swzb2MYypVGhvIU2196ayLCpvKY9erZjCitzmqxYsRcaJd3fac0mX0BEjHwsp98-7gpZF2RY-ocAEUnZ-v-xUoon8cESNdc_6aokf61YpzRJv_kGd6uj8c20TfVFvlYmd0tcUlxOzhkbI-VEfDaPbGLstBeWJJz2PGixjGiManNMnbLQKonjEw-DSVPdFB06WaW_2_27In6qFBBsbxnmG5Inc2lMK8oJWO3IjTe9U1RjXWjV68EUHExZm7CYd4odsqg4nGmewABfjLr_mfNI3SVANKbWX9dvBOIgalb1TramY4bX9edg11E64BZVgihle0QPzPrErvD5jGU7OaIbfMBl_gg59x4Q6xoZ0h8Pw_wc)

[ungolfed version](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVW7btswFN06-CsuHBigLAmKHQQohBDo0o6ZshlCIFuUTYimZJLK41u6ZGk_qn_SrZekZEfqS5Pscw_v81zy6_fm1Rxq-fb2rTVl_PHHh5-Civy4LXKoUsEk2XJJ8q0mVRAE8RquQO9qxaAugUvD9kzNZgUrPUo0O0XspVFBOgPgJZjXhhEHUIp0iwIoZlolQXiDJ9qflM75fEBZXYyb6wztn4Z2Z1hlAxamBfMwXiaLIXeYIJ4KwhG0Rmjlq2FPuWhzczFGfEpJFv5XPTz8X0UYb8PjLsNsTA5H5Y-zxDOYaPg7vrb42Fs8yVs80dtykrflRG_JJG9JMtHdYpK7xd-8OU3sDmxXOYt85JKbB6aOulM7wNWVJ_RxgWvIvSKY1ryWUNYKzAFhdNEyuWOYkVGvPjFr5Fa6Kpd7Rt5HsEuIR4LAM11lsjZ_1CilTkBZTz1X_CUXmr1vwYNq7X_2smPNUMSeOtON4Ka_CmRKUOvuLpDBZp2m2Jd1EFlsfj0PO_ymw7uGbVsuis-YGKku61NRej0IhzvSWe4oH1g2uBxRZZegiinHzylStEqSm6ha3PgzauztdMZXAzy2BkVdUeSUJLdWIuc4_rrYnBa3WXTJ2moHEx8gTieZr6_ksnCTsZHuqW6P5Jg3RERuWohJ2s8O_9SNofehdDeAnXb1btpLsl4u73HCVkb6ULeigC0Dkas9Aybrdn-IoGd1H3jmQoxZ2HODImPQqHqv8iM81xIB1BGXKJVOgwwRbXa5Ztr1CMdj-yqxr9IBWzQ9uttxWNUm5VkQhHz4CnDDc-GCeHfu7hsOf9bp9rJD3G8O7kgBRKf0EnJ0LQfBXd0r1HdRz3ppa0q6rKL-LelmirwI7bafrdzXomQFPDHlFtFTdFeCTQCZrTD-Bewewv5B_AU)

Comment: Could you explain what this output would mean? ([1, 2], ['%', 40, ['*', 'i', 'i']])

Comment: @Simd f(1)=1,f(2)=2,f(i)=(i*i)%40

Comment: I am probably being stupid but that is supposed to make 1,2,4,8,15 but doesn’t seem to.  3*3%40=9 doesn’t it?

Comment: @Simd I made a typo, I meant `40%(i*i)`

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 1488 bytes:

A rather long approach, but designed to be fast, especially on [more common](https://www.tanyakhovanova.com/RecursiveSequences/RecursiveSequences.html) recursive sequences. Explanation of notation coming soon.

```py
from math import*
E=enumerate
def V(s,e):
 e,W=e
 if[0,0]==e[:2]:return all(i==e[-1]for i in s)
 if[0]==e[:1]:return all(a==e[1]*i+e[2]for i,a in E(s,1))
 return all(sum(N*s[i-(W-I)-1]for N,(I,_)in e[0])+i*e[1]+e[2]==a for i,a in E(s,1)if i>max(W-j for _,(j,_)in e[0]))
def C(s,c=[]):
 if[]==s and c:yield c;return
 if s:yield from[*C(s[1:],c+[s[0]]),*C(s[1:],c)]
I=lambda V,i:{(0,V),(V//i,V%i)}
def W(x,y):
 t=[[x,1,0],[y,0,1]]
 while t[-1][0]:q=t[-2][0]//t[-1][0];r=t[-2][0]%t[-1][0];t+=[[r,t[-2][1]-q*t[-1][1],t[-2][2]-q*t[-1][2]]]
 return t[-2]
def D(a,b,x,y,g):
 q=[(0,1,x,y),(0,-1,x,y)]
 while q:
  m,d,X,Y=q.pop(0);m+=d
  if all([X,Y]):yield(X,Y)
  J,K=x+m*(b/g),y-m*(a/g)
  if abs(X)+abs(Y)>abs(J)+abs(K)or 0==all([X,Y]):q+=[(m,d,J,K)]
def f(s):
 for O in range(1,len(s)):
  for J in sorted(C([*E(s)][:O][::-1]),key=len):
   if len(J)==1:
    yield([0,s[O]//(O+1),s[O]%(O+1)],O)
    for u in I(s[O]%J[0][1],O+1):
     j=s[O]//J[0][1]
     yield([[(1,J[0])for _ in range(j)],*u],O);yield([[(j,J[0])],*u],O)
   else:
    q=[(J[0][1],[(1,J[0])],J[1:],s[O])]
    while q:
     x,R,S,v=q.pop(0)
     if[]==S:
      for u in I(v,O+1):yield([R,*u],O)
      continue
     y=S[0][1]
     for i in range(v-1):
      if 0==(v-i)%gcd(x,y):
       g,a,b=W(X:=max(x,y),Y:=min(x,y))
       G=(v-i)//g;A,B=[b,a][x>y]*G,[a,b][x>y]*G;
       A,B=min(D(X,Y,A,B,g),key=lambda x:sum(map(abs,x)))
       q+=[(v-i,[(A*z,l)for z,l in R]+[(B,S[0])],S[1:],i)]
def F(s):
 for i in f(s):
  if V(s,i):return i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVRbb@I4FH7nV/ilkh0OCwmE0iBXmrvKSINUJNrKikYBDDVLAiShA7va3949xw6XdgYR5eRcvu/c7M2hfF5n7d4mf32d5@uUpUn5zEy6WeelV/sidbZLdZ6UujbTczbmBWgR1ZiGB6lrzMxVC1qxlFpFQRzlutzlGUtWK25I1/Dj@TpnhpmMFcK5O2f/jXNCOj/2TF2rwIVAQkFfkM8XGHnhXOxS/sMrlGnwh8adqDh@AL@DnwJjNHKIuvEI0eJJmbDfMM2cmds02SPG0lp/Al9eAAhb7yf0nUoVU8mYPEIVLMlmbBodjF7hu@8SIysrKiW1UXkYqvwohmldFQgYCzirRFy7k6skncwSNgYT/ctbMBbAx82mgfGVEf9Z9ge@hwNRl1KpPfjYaVAHaIEfxzX269msNCupyYgfbSWKAYnN5lHZz0/Kq5OurCNaDs7gx42t50x@XOmCsy6IialqvrXaxD7zBCaAycGC0ttKhQX4pMAiWtBw4inHLfqwFGbwCE9y@9dmveEt0U/rcoZ6bBxNVaEN22w7yFHGmbMBfJf7eurxSXMh4NBAKUGpCpoU/FHU6fUkbuk1cF/fBU6zhUM/o26xZE4JIKJwJcx5QanT5Ie0FXmSLTT3YaUztJDJ2gZ2dfEs6Bn/xJWHyyNiFQ3xibBBAv7WB4kxNoDSoviBkNK3CubqwUNSqCEOhg/rvrDylRVjGArrR1w74rrj1jrASdFEyMkhsaV0GJXJKSt8hZmTXthNPtezRAZvRyz9k@fSeR4NhKNXhXYsNMoj9wk0xhftLfELR3wxWPzt4R5G8HKardO6AzOqfC5LfHF1VSndX2SCv@k6K02201WBcnRZ7@k6cfW9NE7toebj1FFlxNViOjueHfdbAG6sfOCPkaRDbzf1CWWTWfnIzb45gGZz0f8AH6WaQBKr/e0h9r6BQojjR/8YQF6E8pmWFvALj4RbCne89xHdV2my4bibsBdnKruUSIZ9/uD9Ays7O3xTdfdxXfGPMHLdH9num2pzv54313ai2mSqn65nI443q3nd5CYr@VeufGDnP11ul5YAWBtYB1j4xoK6ENg1sBuM@VMQRvTQ1H1v6tgov4VP@70NQbtk@3MOyNd7byGKAPGCVoDA7SAI8SP0O60eWnr@TdsP3yZH3OSPTxufDrnj071@j2y9elhd58ZH8l47DEjb8W964e/Oti4qKkDe6y4lhELYpfzCkNoRdKis1/8B)